# asp:panel show hide not working with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have two panels and a text box on ASPX page. Both the panels contains static text as well as radio buttons along with required field validators. Requirement is as follows.

1. Whenever page loads at very first time, if value of text box is greater than 1000, first panel should not show and 2nd should be displayed.
2. If value is less than 1000, first panel should show and 2nd should not.

Now, the problem is:

Text box value can be changed by the user and thus depending upon the entered value, using jQuery I need to show appropriate panel. I don't want to have labels for each static text and then set the same property for all labels and radio buttons one by one; that is why I used a `<asp:Panel>`.

1. I can't set visible property to false from code behind as then this panel will not be rendered on ASPX page and show, hide will not work.
2. I tried setting `panelNA.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "none")` from code behind but this also doesn't work. As static text and controls are still visible on UI.
3. As i have required field validators on the radio buttons inside a panel, so I want that these validators should be disabled and enabled if panel is hidden or displayed respectively.
4. While saving the things, i can't check the status of panel being visible or not as it is set by jQuery. So it's not available on server side and its always says `visible = true`.

Code:

```
function disablePanelNA() {
  var value = 0;
  value = parseInt($('#<%=txt1.ClientID %>').val(), 10);
  if (value < 1000) {
   $('#<%= panel.ClientID %>').hide();
   $('#<%= panelNA.ClientID %>').show();
  }
  else
  {
    $('#<%= panel.ClientID %>').show();
    $('#<%= panelNA.ClientID %>').hide();
  }
}
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" onChange="disablePanelNA()" />
<asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
<tr>
  <td class="numberColumnNoBold">a.</td>
  <td>Do you want to continue?</td>
  <td align="right">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
      <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
      <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <AjaxRequiredFieldValidator ID="id1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rbl1" 
                                ErrorMessage="Error occured" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="numberColumnNoBold">b.</td>
  <td>Do you want to exit?</td>
  <td align="right">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
      <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
      <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <AjaxRequiredFieldValidator ID="id2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rbl2"
                                ErrorMessage="Error occured again" />
  </td>
</tr>
</asp:panel>

<asp:Panel ID="panelNA" runat="server">
<tr>
  <td class="numberColumnNoBold">a.</td>
  <td>Do you want to continue?</td>
  <td align="right">
    <td align="right">
      <div style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;padding-right:20px;">N/A</div>
    </td>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="numberColumnNoBold">b.</td>
  <td>Do you want to exit?</td>
  <td align="right">
    <div style="text-align:right;font-weight:bold;padding-right:20px;">N/A</div>
  </td>
</tr>
</asp:panel>
```

Comment: Tried formatting your code and it looks like its going to take forever. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind use this

```
pnl.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

For disabling the validators from javascript use this

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= reqfile.ClientID %>'), false);
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= reqfile.ClientID %>'), true);
```

For showing hide the divs you do not need to know the visible status of the div as according to the logic you mentioned the divs are to be hidden or shown based on the value of the textbox.

Also please format you code before pasting.

Comment: I have already tried pnl.Style.Add("display", "none"); from code behind but it doesn't work. Controls inside panel are still being shown. Also show hide of panel is not working. Also i tried disabling enabling of reuired filed validators with above code but the problem is that whenever panel becomes visible using this, atonce these validators get fired and show error messages which is not fine.

Comment: I have rechecked pnl.Style.Add("display", "none"); and it does work.

Comment: Hmmm i am not sure where i am wrong. I tried the same thing with another asp:panel like: asp:Panel ID="panelTest" EnableViewState="true" Runat="server">
                                                                    Hello World                                                            </asp:Panel>. It works for this and do hides the text "Hello world" but when i am putting more tr and td and then inserting more controls (as mentioned in above code) like radio buttons, these controls are still displayed.

Comment: Instead of the table based structure try a div based structure inside the pannel

Comment: Does that really matters? At the end of the day we are hiding panel only. DO these things get treated differently?

Comment: There may be some CSS issue with the table. But it is not recommended to use table layout in HTML for not tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

If you set Visible="false" in .aspx markup / code behind, ASP.Net control will not get rendered in the page.

Better remove Visible="false" set in the panel and add style display:none.

If you want to make it in code behind follow this code

```
pnlUpdateDisplay.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display,"none");
```

Then use

```
$('#<%=pnlUpdateDisplay.ClientID %>').toggle()
```